# Why is node.js so much slower than apache 2.4

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache, performance, benchmarking

A few year ago I tested node.js vs apache 2. The results have been impressive. node.js was really fast, especially with high concurrency.

Yesterday I wanted to show that to someone and.... outch apache 2.4 was much faster.

The setup:

Node.js (Express.js, node 6.2.2)

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World\n');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

Apache 2.4 (serving a php file)

```
<?php
  $foo = "Hello";
  $bar = "World";
  echo "$foo $bar";
?>
```

I launched apache with port 80
Then I launched the node.js app on port 3000 and tested everything with Apache Benchmark

```
ab -r -n 10000 -c 10 http://127.0.0.1/
```

Results:

```
Server Software:        Apache/2.4.18
Server Hostname:        127.0.0.1
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        11 bytes

Concurrency Level:      10
Time taken for tests:   4.439 seconds
Complete requests:      10000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      1980000 bytes
HTML transferred:       110000 bytes
Requests per second:    2252.97 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       4.439 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.444 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          435.63 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    1   1.3      0      12
Processing:     1    3   1.8      3      88
Waiting:        0    3   1.5      3      38
Total:          1    4   1.8      4      91

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%      4
  66%      4
  75%      5
  80%      5
  90%      6
  95%      7
  98%      9
  99%     10
 100%     91 (longest request)
```

Node.js

```
ab -r -n 10000 -c 10 http://127.0.0.1/
```

Results:

```
Server Software:
Server Hostname:        127.0.0.1
Server Port:            3000

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        19 bytes

Concurrency Level:      10
Time taken for tests:   8.513 seconds
Complete requests:      10000
Failed requests:        0
Non-2xx responses:      10000
Total transferred:      4020000 bytes
HTML transferred:       190000 bytes
Requests per second:    1174.64 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       8.513 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.851 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          461.14 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.3      0       7
Processing:     1    8   4.4      8      69
Waiting:        0    8   4.3      7      69
Total:          2    8   4.4      8      69

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%      8
  66%      9
  75%     10
  80%     10
  90%     12
  95%     15
  98%     20
  99%     23
 100%     69 (longest request)
```

The same if I test for n=1000, c=100 ... or higher
Apache is always twice as fast.

Did there change anything? Did they speed up apache 2.4 massively? Or did node.js get old and slow?

I really remember that node.js was faster as soon as there was a concurrency higher than 5 or 10...

Am I am wrong? Any comment appreciated.

Kind regards
Martin

**UPDATE**

I found this article in the web http://zgadzaj.com/benchmarking-nodejs-basic-performance-tests-against-apache-php

I cannot reproduce those results. Apache is faster when I try the same settings.

Comment: These are just my thoughts about the subject and my knowledge about node and apache, not sure if they are  the answer:

Node being only one thread handling all these requests would surely spend more time on handling these small requests you are setting up, compared to apache which I believe is multi threaded? However, if you had a variety of requests (some small, some medium and some heavy), nodejs would excell, being able to quickly switch between all jobs, not being tied to the heavy jobs, while the threads of apache would be working on heavy jobs until completion? Just a thought.

Comment: @Stian I totally agree. Maybe the test setup is not really the one that shows the advantages of node.js. In such cases apache is probably always faster...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the 2 sets of results.
Are they the same?
There is a difference here:
Non-2xx responses:      10000

Your test results are not the same so we can't say anything about performance until that is fixed.